# How do extract path without variables in Akka Http?

Tags: scala, akka-http

I wish to obtain path without variables, for example, having `api/test/132/123` I would like to get `api/test`. What is the best way of doing it? Can I get this done by using path directives - `pathPrefix`? So far I can image something like this, e.g., pass variables and remove them from string.

```
class UriSpec extends WordSpecLike with Matchers with ScalatestRouteTest {

  "Uri" should {

    "remain without identifiers" in new Scope {
      Get("/api/test/132/123") ~> testRoute ~> check {
        status should be(OK)
        responseAs[String] should be("/api/test")
      }
    }
  }

  private trait Scope extends Directives {

    def testRoute: Route =
      path("api" / "test" / LongNumber / LongNumber) { (n1, n2) =>
        extractMatchedPath { path =>
          complete(OK -> path.toString.replace(s"/$n1", "").replace(s"/$n2", ""))
        }
      }
  }
}
```

Thank you for your help. Sorry, I didn't managed to figure out how to use existing directives, nor find existing solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea to use `pathPrefix` was along the right lines.  You can use that to deal with the base path and then have a separate level to deal with the variables, extracting out the current matched path in between:

```
      def testRoute: Route =
         pathPrefix("api" / "test") {
            extractMatchedPath { basePath =>
               path(LongNumber / LongNumber) { (n1, n2) =>
                  complete(OK -> basePath.toString)
               }
            }
         }
```

That means you then have the base path separated out without the need to remove the variable parts.

Comment: Thanks, Steve. This solution is very good for that kind of scenario. Just wondering is there a way of combining `pathPrefix` and `path` to remove path variables in the middle too, for example, `api/123/test`?

Comment: Not in any nice way.  You'd have to use multiple nested pathPrefixes, one for each fixed part and one for each variable part.  And then do extractMatchedPath on each fixed part and compose.   So depends what the "real" use case is here given that you actually know what the path is for each route really.

The thing to remember is the matching just remembers what is left of the path to consume.  And it does not care how a segment was consumed (via fixed string matching or variable extraction).  So that info is gone within the next directive.

Comment: The only way I could imagine you could do it is building your own custom directive which worked like `path` but also tracked which segments were variables and which were fixed.  That would likely be hard and require a deep understanding of the existing routing mechanics.

Comment: Thanks Steve, that's perfectly makes sense